# Javadoc View equivalent in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I can see Javadoc when I hover on a method. However, I would like to see it in a fixed pane at the bottom or side. Eclipse has a Javadoc View for this. Does Android Studio have something similar?

Comment: Windows : Ctrl + Q

Comment: Thanks. For others: Click the pin icon to prevent the popup from disappearing. Click settings icon and unselect floating mode or window mode to make it a fixed part of the UI.